# Android Layout Right Align

Tags: android, layout, right-align

I have the following layout in place

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">


        <WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/webview" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"  android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"  android:layout_weight="13">
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1">
                    <ImageButton android:background="@null" android:id="@+id/back" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/back" android:padding="10dip" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1">
                <ImageButton android:background="@null" android:id="@+id/forward" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/forward" android:padding="10dip" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent"    android:layout_weight="1" >
                <ImageButton android:background="@null" android:id="@+id/special"   android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/barcode" android:padding="10dip" android:layout_gravity="right"/>
        </RelativeLayout>




    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

For the purpose of this question, I am only concerned about the lower half of the layout. Right now it contains 3 imagebuttons. The first 2, I want right next to each other left aligned. The third one, I want to be aligned to the right side.

As is, the first 2 buttons are where I want them to be, but the 3rd is stubbernly staying left-aligned. How would I make it right aligned.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

The layout is extremely inefficient and bloated. You don't need that many `LinearLayout`s. In fact you don't need any `LinearLayout` at all.

Use only one `RelativeLayout`. Like this.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageButton android:background="@null"
        android:id="@+id/back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/back"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
    <ImageButton android:background="@null"
        android:id="@+id/forward"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/forward"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/back"/>
    <ImageButton android:background="@null"
        android:id="@+id/special"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/barcode"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I believe the answer to the asked question is to use:
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
It's a little tough to see in your answer.

Comment: @eriyg That's the answer, it aligns the view/layout itself (within its parent), not the child (as `gravity` does). Better use `android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"` instead now to also support right-to-left layouts.

Answer (score 22):

You can do all that by using just one `RelativeLayout` (which, btw, don't need `android:orientation` parameter). So, instead of having a `LinearLayout`, containing a bunch of stuff, you can do something like:

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/the_first_one"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/the_first_one"/>
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

As you noticed, there are some XML parameters missing. I was just showing the basic parameters you had to put. You can complete the rest.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to use [LinearLayout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html), you can do alignment with `layout_weight` with `Space` element.

E.g. following layout places `textView` and `textView2` next to each other and `textView3` will be right-aligned

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView2" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView3" />
</LinearLayout>
```

you can achieve the same effect without `Space` if you would set `layout_weight` to `textView2`. It's just that I like things more separated, plus to demonstrate `Space` element.

```
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView2" />
```

Note that [you should (not must though) set](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html#Weight) `layout_width` explicitly as it will be recalculated according to it's weight anyway (same way you should set height in elements of vertical `LinearLayout`). For other layout performance tips see [Android Layout Tricks](http://android-developers.blogspot.ru/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-1.html) series.

Answer (score 3):

This is an example for a **RelativeLayout**:

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayout=(RelativeLayout)vi.findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayoutLeft);
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)relativeLayout.getLayoutParams();
                params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
                relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
```

With another kind of layout (example LinearLayout) you just simply has to change *RelativeLayout* for *LinearLayout*.

Answer (score 2):

To support older version Space can be replaced with View as below. Add this view between after left most component and before right most component. This view with weight=1 will stretch and fill the space

```
    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
```

Complete sample code is given here. It has has 4 components. Two arrows will be on the right and left side. The Text and Spinner will be in the middle.

```
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnGenesis"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:src="@drawable/prev" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblVerseHeading"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerVerses"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnExodus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:src="@drawable/next" />
</LinearLayout>
```