# How to create backward and forward icon button of webview in android studio 2.1?

Tags: android

I can only create the backward and forward text button of webview in android studio. Is anyone can help to show me how to create backward and forward icon button of webview in android studio 2.1?

```
<WebView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />


<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Share"
    android:id="@+id/sharebutton"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="#37b5db"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Back"
    android:id="@+id/backbutton"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/sharebutton"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/sharebutton"
    android:background="#f2a64a"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Forward"
    android:id="@+id/forwardbutton"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/sharebutton"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sharebutton"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:background="#f2a64a"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />
```

Comment: use image button and set image as back and forward .

Answer (score 0):

You would use an `ImageButton` instead of a `Button`. Like here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4305648